# Parsing variable length data with X escapes in Python 2

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I am trying to parse elements in this string with Python 2.7.

r='\x01\x99h\x1bu=https://cpr.sm/eIOxaAZ-he'

'\x01' ,  '\x99',  and 'h' are all separate elements r[0],r[1],r[2].

But I am trying to extract variable length data here, specifically, the concatenation of '\x99' and 'h' in positions r[1] and r[2].  That concatenation will then be decoded via LEB 128 format.  But the portion I'm looking for, in this case '\x99h', can be of variable length.  Sometimes it will be one byte, so just r[1], sometimes more, like r[1]+r[2]+r[3].  The only way to know is when the next X escape '\x' occurs.

But I can't for the life of my figure out how to parse this data for the '\x' escapes into a more manageable format.

TL:DR, how do I replace '\x' escapes in my string, or at least identify where they occur.  And also, str.replace('\x','') doesnt work, I get "invalid \x escape".

Comment: It seems that you want to use raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer this, you need to understand something.

Every character in a string is a byte.  Every byte can be represented as a `\x`-escaped literal.  (recall: 8 bits in a byte, 2**8 == 256 possible values; hence the range `\x00` to `\xFF`)  When those literals happen to fall within ASCII-printable ranges and you print out the string, python will print the associated ASCII character instead of the `\x`-escaped version.

But make no mistakes - they are **100% equivalent**.

```
In [7]: '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64'
Out[7]: 'hello world'
```

So, let's assume there's some meaningful boundary that you can give me.  (there *has* to be one, since a variable-length encoding like LEB128 needs some method to say "hey, the data stops here")  Perhaps `\x1b`, which is the [ASCII escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).  Were you looking for *that* escape character?

If so, extracting it is quite easy:

```
r='\x01\x99h\x1bu=https://cpr.sm/eIOxaAZ-he'

r[1:r.index('\x1b')]
Out[15]: '\x99h'
```

And then you can run that through whatever LEB128 decoding algorithm you'd like.  The [one on the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128#Decode_unsigned_integer) seems serviceable, and gives me:

```
leb128_decode(r[1:r.index('\x1b')])
Out[16]: (13337, 2) # 13337 is the value encoded by these two bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either use raw strings (preferable), where no character would be treated as special character or escape `\` in original string to avoid making `\x` a special character.

```
>>> str = r'hello\nhello\t\nhello\r'
>>> str.replace(r'\n', 'x')
'helloxhello\\txhello\\r'
```

or

```
>>> str = r'hello\nhello\t\nhello\r'
>>> str.replace('\\n', 'x')
'helloxhello\\txhello\\r'
```